Handshake Header Check Failed When Starting Thin Client in Ignite
I am attempting to start up Ignite with TLS mode turned on as described in Ignite's documentation. This is working but when I try to connect a Thin Client the server reports the error below:
Handshake header check failed: 493
I have created a rootCA .pfx file that serves as the KeyStore in the Server's SslContextFactory. The server start's up fine and logs the expected message according to the documentation:
Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=on]
The problem comes in when I start a Thin Client with SSL settings. I created a pfx file for the client from the rootCA that is being used as the KeyStore for the server. I specify the path and password to the client's pfx file in the SslStreamFactory for the client. When the client calls Ignition.StartClient() it immediately reports the error below:
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream
At the same time the Server log reports this error:
native error: java.io.IOException: Handshake header check failed: 493
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientMessage.readFrom(ClientMessage.java:186)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioMessageParser.decode(ClientListenerNioMessageParser.java:66)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3753)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:175)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1379)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2527)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2282)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1911)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
What is the cause of these errors? When I remove the SslStreamFactory from the Client's configuration it connects without issue.
I was able to get the full stack trace from the client and see that it's failing in the SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient() code:
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__1761.MoveNext()    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__1751.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.d__172.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.SslStreamFactory.Create(Stream stream, String targetHost)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.GetSocketStream(Socket socket, IgniteClientConfiguration cfg, String host)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration, EndPoint endPoint, String host, Nullable1 version, Action1 topVerCallback, Marshaller marshaller)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.Connect(SocketEndpoint endPoint)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.GetNextSocket()
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration config, Marshaller marsh, TransactionsClient transactions)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.StartClient(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)

SSL/TLS is not enabled on the server, so you get the handshake error - the server interprets the client data without encryption.
You have enabled SSL/TLS for inter-node communication, but not for thin client connector.
Please follow the SSL/TLS for Thin Clients and JDBC/ODBC section on the same documentation page.

For the thin client my application creates a SslStreamFactory and specifies a certificate and certificate password which should be enough right? That article mentions an "sslEnabled" property but I'm using .NET and don't see that property anywhere. Is there something other than creating an SslStreamFactory that I need to do?

@DeviantSpark you have to enable SSL/TLS on the server side. Currently .NET client has it enabled, tries to talk to the server, but the server does not expect TLS handshake. Please configure the Ignite cluster accordingly.

I found that although the server was logging "tls/ssl=on" the ClientConnectorConfiguration of the IgniteConfiguration was not configured to actually turn on SSL on the server. In fact, it appears to be a defect and isn't currently possible. In ClientConnectorConfigurationParityTest of the Ignite code there is a comment about 4 properties that needed added in the future and "isSslEnabled" is one that needs to be set for this to work. I had to comment out my ClientConnectorConfiguration and instead specify a SpringConfigUrl path to a file that sets "sslEnabled" to true and then it all works.
